# Should a function go in one/both of two classes or be free-standing?

Tags: java, c++, oop

I am relatively new to OOP. Sometimes I come across situations where I'm not sure where a method should go. I will try to give a minimal example; I hope I don't go overboard and make it too abstract.

Say I have a `Point` class which holds the position of a point, and a `Line` class which holds the equation of a line. I now need a method that computes the (perpendicular) distance between a `Point` and a `Line`. I could do:

- Point::distance_to_line(Line L)
- Line::distance_to_point(Point P)
- a free-standing function: point_line_distance(Line L, point P)

Is there a preferred way in OOP in general, or is it language-dependant? In C++ a free-standing function is an option, but from my limited understanding of Java, it does not allow free-standing functions. In that case would you create a class like `PointLineDistanceCalculator`?

Comment: If I was posed such a problem I would do the following. Make `GeometryHelper` `.h` and `.cpp` files that have a bunch of free functions. They would do stuff like `point_line_distance`, `line_intersection`, etc.

Comment: Does it make sense for a point to have methods to calculate its distance to every single type of shape under the sun? Probably not. So it should probably be a non-member function, which allows you to keep the Point interface simple and clean. And your function names don't have to have long names such as `point_line_distance`, but could simply be called `distance`.

Comment: As long as they're functionally identical, i'd put it as a member of the line class only to reduce dependencies between point and line given Line already has a dependency on point, there's no reason to introduce the opposite

Comment: Given your example, I would choose to implement it as a free function. However, I would put `Point`, `Line` and any other free functions in a common namespace like `Geometry`.

Answer (score 4):

Your 3rd option of some other place that is not in the `Point` or `Line` class is the best option.

`Points` shouldn't have to know about `Lines` and vice versa. Otherwise, they will be tightly coupled.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling

However, there can be some other class that knows about both.

In java, I would probably made a 3rd `Distance` class or `DistanceCalculator` that could compute distances between several objects.

```
Distance.between(Point a, Point b)

Distance.between(Point a, line l)
```

etc

Comment: There's no need for a class though, unless you're using a language that doesn't have non-member functions.

Answer (score 1):

In java you could always create the free standing function as a static method of one of the two classes (or of a third helper class).

I don't think there's a preferred way in general, but you could have all three for the most flexibility, and reuse the code.

For example, one method would hold the logic :

```
class Point {
...
   float distToLine (Line l) {
       ....
       return some result;
   }
...
}
```

and then the other methods will call the original method :

```
class Line {
...
   float distToPoint (Point p) {
      return p.distToLine (this);
   }
...
   static float pointToLineDistance (Point p, Line l) {
      return p.distToLine (l);
   }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A fourth option is to find/construct a common ancestor in the class hierarchy which could 
be something like "GeometricEntity". Anything for which "distance to annother GeometricEntity" has a meaning.